# Dynamic html elements show only when going through debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf

I'm working on project that simulates Twitter and I'm using HTML + JS on client and WCF services on server side (ajax calls), and Neo4J as database.

For example:

in `$(document).ready(function ()`


there is DisplayTweets service call -> `DisplayTweets(username)`

```
function DisplayTweets(userName) {
    $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url: "Service.svc/DisplayTweets", // Location of the service               
                    data: { userName: userName },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
                    dataType: "json",                   
                    processdata: true, //True or False
                    success: function (msg) //On Successfull service call
                    {                           
                            DisplayTweetsSucceeded(msg);                            
                    },
                    error: function () // When Service call fails
                    {
                        alert("DISPLAY TWEETS ERROR");
                    }
                }
            );
}
```

and then `DisplayTweetsSucceeded(msg)` where msg would be json array of users tweets

```
function DisplayTweetsSucceeded(result)
{  
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        var tweet = JSON.parse(result[i]);

        var id_tweet = tweet.id;
        var content_tweet = tweet.content;
        var r_count_tweet = tweet.r_count;

        NewTweet(null, id_tweet, content_tweet, r_count_tweet);          
    }

}
```

Function `NewTweet` is used for dynamic generating of tweets.

Problem is when I first load html page, nothing shows up, neither when I load it multiple times again. It only shows when I go through Firebug, line by line.

I'm presuming that maybe getting data from database is slower, but I'm not sure and also have no idea how to solve this. Any help will be very much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Quick and easy way to debug you code `console.log('Start **** Function');`  **-**  `console.log('End of **** Function');` I would also add `console.log(msg);`  within the ajax success to review the data returned.

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you so much for the advice, I tried it and it seems now that one variable that needs to get data from database is empty but dynamic html element generation continues nevertheless. I'm still trying to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Best way is to break this down into sections using console.log() so you can make sure functions are being called and what data is in the function. Keep in mind, this isn't going to fix/change the problem in hand but this will help you find the problem.